How to access a video as *apm file in OBS?
I'm an OBS newbie and completely screwed up by mistakenly saving my video output as an *.apm (audio) file. I tried to extract the file from the apm wrapper using GIMP (Mac) and Image Converter Plus (Windows) but without success.
What options, if any, do I have?
Thanks for your time and help.
J.
